# Pandas - remove combination of string and number from column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Below is a subset of a `pandas` `dataframe` with a column like the below

```
   No                   Name
0    1   SOU 01 Sungai Dingin
1    2                  PKS 2
2    3                 Mill 3
3    4    Tanah Kerajaan Mill
4    5                MAS POM
5    6           SOU 20 Chaah
6    7     SOU 03 Elphil Mill
7    8       SOU 08 East Mill
8    9  SOU 04 Flemington POM
9   10    SOU 30A Jeleta Bumi
10  11         SOU 30B Mostyn
11  12          KLK - Mill 02
12  13           Chini 02 POM
13  14      SOU 05 Selaba POM
14  15     SOU 9A Sepang Mill
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to use regex in python to easily remove just the `'SOU XX'` or `'SOU XXX'` combination of string and numbers in that column without affecting the other text in the column?

The output would be something like the below:

```
    No                 Name
0    1        Sungai Dingin
1    2                PKS 2
2    3               Mill 3
3    4  Tanah Kerajaan Mill
4    5              MAS POM
5    6                Chaah
6    7          Elphil Mill
7    8            East Mill
8    9       Flemington POM
9   10          Jeleta Bumi
10  11               Mostyn
11  12        KLK - Mill 02
12  13         Chini 02 POM
13  14           Selaba POM
14  15          Sepang Mill
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex `^SOU \S{2,3}` (note the trailing space at the end) with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'^SOU \S{2,3} ', '')
```

Result:

```
    No                 Name
0    1        Sungai Dingin
1    2                PKS 2
2    3               Mill 3
3    4  Tanah Kerajaan Mill
4    5              MAS POM
5    6                Chaah
6    7          Elphil Mill
7    8            East Mill
8    9       Flemington POM
9   10          Jeleta Bumi
10  11               Mostyn
11  12        KLK - Mill 02
12  13         Chini 02 POM
13  14           Selaba POM
14  15          Sepang Mill
```

The regex `^SOU \S{2,3}` matches the letters "SOU" plus any two or three non-space characters `\S`, but only if they appear at the start of the string thanks to the `^` anchor.

Comment: Sure but why bother with re.compile and just not go for the regex string right away?

Comment: @AntonvBR Newbie mistake - I thought `str.replace` could also replace literal strings, not just regexes. Thanks for the heads up.